# First Cloud Staging Deployment - home page not available

Tags: magento2, cloud, staging

I did my first merge from integration to staging environments, however the staging home page is not available.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for the current version of cloud 2.2 you will need to change the core options data to match the access url. Your PM should be able to email the instructions.